Upgrading bitnami/moodle container
I have a setup based on what is described in https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/moodle
# Copyright Broadcom, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: APACHE-2.0

version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:11.3
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_moodle
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_moodle
      - MARIADB_CHARACTER_SET=utf8mb4
      - MARIADB_COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    volumes:
      - ./mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb
  moodle:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/moodle:4.3
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    environment:
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=bn_moodle
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_moodle
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - ./moodle_data:/bitnami/moodle
      - ./moodledata_data:/bitnami/moodledata
    depends_on:
      - mariadb

The moodle version in site administration - notifications: Moodle 4.3.2 (Build: 20231222)
I want to upgrade the moodle instance to moodle:4.4 and for some reason thought it'd be as simple as updating the docker-compose.yml and restarting the stack. But, it does seem that there is much to do and I don't quite understand how to do this.
I also noticed that I would like to have all the language versions available so I created Dockerfile with only FROM bitnami/moodle and docker-compose.yml
# Copyright Broadcom, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: APACHE-2.0

version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:11.3
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_moodle
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_moodle
      - MARIADB_CHARACTER_SET=utf8mb4
      - MARIADB_COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    volumes:
      - ./mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb
  moodle:
    #image: docker.io/bitnami/moodle:4.4
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - WITH_ALL_LOCALES=yes
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    environment:
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=bn_moodle
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_moodle
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - ./moodle_data:/bitnami/moodle
      - ./moodledata_data:/bitnami/moodledata
    depends_on:
      - mariadb

Could someone provide a step-by-step instructions how I get from old setup to new setup without losing my data?

Do you have a solution now?
